# How to securely attach a wooden plank to a wooden banister

Tags: woodworking

[image]

I need to securely attach a wooden plank to a banister. The plank is temporary so I need a method that won't do permanent damage to the banister (I do not mind plugging holes and using touch up paint if needed)

Please see attached diagram. I don't know if nails or screws are the right approach. Or if I need to drill holes and use one of those plastic tube inserts.

I need to do this because I need to attach a baby gate to the banister but the irregular shape of the banister prevents me from using any pre-made baby gates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use screws

1. The baby gate will tear the banister up so you need something to protect it. A 2x4 is a good solution
2. Screws come out easily and leave small holes. 2 screws total (I'd suggest 3" myself) should do the trick. Wood putty the holes and stain and/or lacquer

One tip: put something like a piece of plastic (maybe a plastic bag) between the banister and the 2x4. The lacquer finish (or paint) might get damaged by being sucked up to the 2x4

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to use a wood anchor for the screws or do they go directly into the banister.

Comment: I'd just use a drill and power them in directly(anchors would need an even bigger hole). If you're worried about puckering or splitting, pre-drilling is advisable